# Sencha Touch : FLUD style multiple scrolling panel

Tags: ipad, sencha-touch, extjs

I am trying to develop a [FLUD](http://www.theflud.com/) style list of Panels by Sencha Touch. All the panels will be scrollable by themselves. Here are the images of what I want [image: A panel like this] inspired by a this FLUD panel : [image: FLUD]

Now, if I just create a Ext.List of Ext.Panel (or may be a Tab Panel) with overflowed items, can they all be tapped and scrolled within themselves? Or can you provide some other idea to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, I was just playing with this idea for work. You've probably seen this already, but here's some starter code if you haven't:

```
new Ext.Container({
  xtype:container,
  layout:'hbox',
  scroll:'horizontal',
  items: [
    new Ext.Container({
      width:'250',
      height:'100',
      cls:'css-class-you-want-for-these-buttons',
      listeners: {
        click: {
          element: 'el',
          fn: function() {
            alert('beep')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Then dump like 10+ of those items in there and viola. Just got to figure out how to customize the scrollbar (that's the part I'm on right now). Good luck!